# Restricting types not related through inheritance without using instanceOf by creating own class hierarchy

Tags: java, database, inheritance, lombok

Restricting types not related through inheritance without using `instanceOf` by creating own class hierarchy. It needs to interact with a key value data store, will convert to object before putting, but needs to convert back to fields after getting from DB with `Function<Object,Field>`. Something about this with regards to inheritance doesn't seem right, although it works.

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;

/**
 * Field, placeholder for a type that can be stored in db
 */
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Field<T> {
    @Getter
    private T featureValue;

    Field(@NonNull T value) {
        this.featureValue = value;
    }

    public static class Factory {
    }
}
//convert object to feature value (since ddb returns Map<String, Object> on Item.asMap)
//convert particular type of object to feature value (say Integer, String)
//abstract Field from(T value);
//convert feature value to particular type, call from drvd (from base => obj)
//enum or getEnum for some type expressed as string factory

/**
 * Field for a boolean type
 */
public class BooleanField extends Field<Boolean> {
    public BooleanField(Boolean value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public static BooleanField fromObject(Object value) {
        return new BooleanField((Boolean) value);
    }
}

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Field for a list data type, holds a list of Field
 */
public class ListField extends Field<List<Field>> {
    public ListField(List<Field> value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public static ListField fromObject(Object value) {
        return new ListField((List<Field>) value);
    }
}


import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Field for a map type, holds a map of String to Field
 */
public class MapField extends Field<Map<String, Field>> {
    public MapField(Map<String, Field> value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public static MapField fromObject(Object value) {
        return new MapField((Map<String, Field>) value);
    }
}


/**
 * Field for a Numeric type
 */
public class NumericField extends Field<Number> {
    public NumericField(Number value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public static NumericField fromObject(Object value) {
        return new NumericField((Number) value);
    }
}


import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Field for a set data type
 */
public class SetField extends Field<Set<Field>> {
    public SetField(Set<Field> value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public static SetField fromObject(Object value) {
        return new SetField((Set<Field>) value);
    }
}


/**
 * Field for a string type
 */
public class StringField extends Field<String> {
    public StringField(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public static StringField fromObject(Object value) {
        return new StringField((String) value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your use case say that you need all those implementations or is this done only for having the fromObject method?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: I have put up what the what this code was supposed to replace [here](http://ideone.com/vyIBRx), it is mostly to avoid excessive if else as in the link

Comment: I'm trying make a better answer but without any `instanceOf` you get stuck. see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893297/method-overloading-with-dynamic-casting  or is there any other way to know what type of object it is?

Answer (score 4):

You can create the same thing by not creating all those subclasses. I also see that you can't use the `instanceOf` method. My first intention was getting this test method to work:

```
System.out.println(Field.fromObject(new ArrayList()).getFeatureValue().getClass());
System.out.println(Field.fromObject(new Integer(6)).getFeatureValue());
System.out.println(Field.fromObject(new Integer(6)).getFeatureValue().getClass());
System.out.println(Field.fromObject(Boolean.TRUE)); // null or error
```

As you can see, I call `Field` and not an implementation of the `Field` class. But I also want the correct class back as what class I put in there, so the output should be:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
6
class java.lang.Integer
null
```

In order that `Boolean` is a type what can't be created. After searching on this topic you come always back to `instanceOf` or what you did. The thing what I wanted is something I can refactor really easy, so **it needed to be on 1 place** to refactor.

`Enum` could help me with that, but still having trouble with subclasses what also need to be valid. (`ArrayList` if `List` is allowed)

I refactored your code to this. If you need to create the subclasses, you could still look at the `static` method.

```
public class Field<T> {

    private T featureValue;

    Field(T value) {
        this.featureValue = value;
    }

    public T getFeatureValue() {
        return featureValue;
    }

    public static <T> Field<T> fromObject(T value) {
        for (Allowed allow : Allowed.values()) {
            if (allow.getClazz().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                return new Field<>(value);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private enum Allowed {

        INTEGER(Integer.class),
        STRING(String.class),
        LIST(List.class);

        private final Class clazz;

        private Allowed(Class clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public Class getClazz() {
            return clazz;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, we iterate the `Enum` values to check the restrictions. With this solution you can add also the following test:

```
List<String> list  = Field.fromObject(new ArrayList<String>()).getFeatureValue();
```

As you can see, no casting is required.

**The next is broken code:**

```
List<String> list  = Field.fromObject(new ArrayList<Boolean>()).getFeatureValue();
```

which is also good because these are 2 different types.

Comment: Thanks, this still allows the list to contain any type since the compiler gives an error "cannot select from parameterized type" when `List<String>.class` is added to the Allowed enum. I have put up what the what my code was supposed to replace [here](http://ideone.com/vyIBRx)

Comment: Yeah, it's no inheritance anymore. I had a suspicion it was for soms online test. Do the create function need to be static?

Comment: no it doesn't I was trying to restrict which subclasses can be created by making the base class ctor package access and using a factory pattern (which is not in the code yet), also see the comments after the Field class